# How to render a template column of a grid, in a detailRow?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

Here's my situation. I have a main grid, where each row expands to show 2 tabs. The first tab has another grid, with dynamically columns. One of the columns needs to display a template with a modified Kendo Menu (in order for it to look like a dropdown).

When the column is rendered in the main grid, it works just fine. However, when I move that column to the sub-grid, I just see the list, without the kendo menu applied to it.

Two workarounds I tried:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OmiBu/3

Visuals:

[Good and Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSsMP.jpg)

Comment: Your demos doesn't looks like the screenshot neither the description in your question..

Comment: Because I can't duplicate the data on dojo very easily. But the code is very similar and I can duplicate the issue in the simplified example.